# How to start an Android application when the phone boots up?

Tags: android, boot

How to start an Android application when the phone boots up? I have done this previously using a **BroadcastReceiver** with the **BOOT_COMPLETED** intent. Are there any alternative ways to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, I think that the way you describe is the only one.